# Autosys monthly job schedule

Tags: jobs, autosys

I know how to run autosys job on certain day in a week but how can i run once in a month.. like if i have to run job1 on 2nd day of the month .. any help would be good for me.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a day of the month with an extended calendar with the condition `MNTHD#nn`, where `nn` is the `nn`th day of the month.

The extended calendar can be defined like

```
extended_calendar: second_of_month
condition: MNTHD#2
```

and you can include the calendar as the `run_calendar` attribute of your job like

```
insert_job: job1
run_calendar: second_of_month
```

Find more information [here](https://communities.ca.com/thread/241757515) on the different conditions for an extended calendar.

Comment: Can the `extended_calendar:` declaration go into the same JIL file as the job?

Answer (score 0):

Use a run calendar. Create a calendar with the days you want the job to run on and add that calendar to the job. The current version of Autosys, R11 allows you to use logic to create calendars. For example the first business day of the month.